# Dynatree Deselect node (or Remove active class) when clicking on a link <a>

Tags: jquery, css, dynatree

I'm trying to deselect the current node in a dynatree.

```
node.deactivate(); // doesn't work
node.focus(false); // doesn't exist
```

I tried to remove the classes that highlight the focused/activated node :

This worked but destroy the complete CSS of the tree :

```
$("#tree span").removeClass();
```

But this did NOT work, and I checked carefully the class names :

```
$("#tree span").removeClass("dynatree-active dynatree-focused");
```

Question is : how to deselect an active node, at least by removing the visual highlight ? Thx

Comment: I've just tried deactivate() and it worked for me. I had a button that when clicked did the following: var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode"); node.deactivate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deactivate()` doesn't work for me, I give you my alternative solution:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
   node.select(false);
});
```